# Autolayout persists on simulator - XCode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad, ios-simulator

I'm having some issues with the rotate/autolayout feature.

It's an Universal App, Supported Interface Orientations just Landscape.
Autolayout uncheck in both storyboards.

But, iPad simulator still rotating and moving around all items once it gets "physically" rotated...

How can I stop this Autolayout for real?

Thank you very much

Comment: Did you change your supported interface orientations after creating the scenes in the storyboard?

Comment: I can't remember... I would say no, scenes were first.

Comment: But I couldn't say really...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put these methods in individual `viewControllers` to control the supported orientations or whether or not they will auto-rotate.

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
    //or UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait, depending on what you want
}
```

As a note, the above method is good enough to support both landscape orientations.  Including the below method will lock the screen to just ONE of the four orientation schemes.  (Turning the device 180 degrees won't rotate it--it will appear upside down.)

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: AWESOME! Solved right away just with the first method. Thank you! PS: Question. So the Supported Interface Orientations buttons did nothing... Right? Why?

Comment: They do stuff... but I've seen them act separately from expectations before as well.  I think that, suppose you leave it on all orientations, create your storyboard, then add some scenes.  Then you change it to landscape only.  I think the scenes that were already added (as a minimum these scenes anyway) are still stuck on all orientations.

Comment: Moreover, I think there's a method similar to the first one in my answer that you can put in the `appDelegate` or somewhere and it will apply it as the default for all `viewControllers`.

Comment: OK, my bad, I trusted those buttons. I accepted your response already. Very kind of you.